# how to fit a table into one page using longtable package?

Tags: tabularray

I have asked here before and tested one of the most suitable answers, but there is still an error that I cannot find a solution for. In addition, the table is still split into two pages in a way that is not acceptable to me.

Originally I wished to replicate this table:

[image: wished table]

The code is:

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{report}
    
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \definecolor{cyan}{rgb}{0.9, 0.9, 0.98}
    \usepackage{tabularray}
    \UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{longtable}
    
    \begin{document}
    
     \centering
        \refstepcounter{table}
    \DefTblrTemplate{firsthead, middlehead,lasthead}{default}{} % <---
    \DefTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{normal}{\scriptsize\textit{Continued on the next page}}
    \SetTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{normal}
        \begin{longtblr}[
     label={table:1}   
                        ]{
                colspec={|l l l},
                colsep=6pt,
                rows=5pt,
                row{odd} = {bg=cyan},
                row{1,2} = {bg=white},
                row{2} = {rowsep=0pt},
                row{3} = {font=\bfseries},
                column{1} = {bg=white, colsep=3pt},
                vline{1} = {abovepos = 1, belowpos = 1},
                rowhead=3
            }
        & \SetCell[c=2]{c} \textbf{Table \thetable}. Parameters for protein solvation calculations using APBSmem. & \\
        \cline[1.5pt]{2,3} & & \\[-6pt]
        \cline[1.5pt]{2,3} & Parameter & Value \\
        \cline[1.5pt,gray]{2,3} & Calculation type & Protein solvation \\
        & Grid Dimensions & $\qtyproduct{289 x 289 x 257}{\angstrom}$ \\
        & Coarse Grid Lengths & $\qtyproduct{202.889 x 202.915 x 185.759}{\angstrom}$ \\
        & Fine Grid Lengths & $\qtyproduct{139.347 x 139.362 x 129.27}{\angstrom}$ \\
        & Counter-Ions & 1.0, 0.154, 1.65 \\
        & & $-1.0$, 0.154, 1.67 \\
        & Protein Dielectric & 2.0 \\
        & Solvent Dielectric & 80.0 \\
        & Membrane Dielectric & 8.0 \\
        & Headgroup Dielectric & 80.0 \\
        & Boundary Conditions & Focus \\
        & Solvent probe radius (srad) & 1.4 \\
        & Surface sphere density (sdens) & 10 \\
        & Temperature & 298.15 \\
        & Z-position of membrane bottom & $-23.9$ \\
        & Membrane thickness & 47.8 \\
        & Headgroup thickness & -- \\
        & Upper exclusion radius & 0 \\
        & Lower exclusion radius & 0 \\
        \cline[1.5pt]{2,3}
    \end{longtblr}
    
    \end{document}
```

which produced the following table:

[image]

The issues are:

1. `Package xcolor Error: Undefined color belowpos`.
2. caption: should be "table 1" instead of "table 2"
3. It is split into two pages. I know that the sentence "continued on the next page" is in my code, but as soon as I leave it out, the table gets totally messed up.

Comment: When I compile that code I get "Table 1" not "Table 2", I don't get any xcolor error, and nothing gets screwed up if I remove "`\scriptsize\textit{Continued on the next page}`". You need to post code that actually demonstrates the problems you are having.

Comment: Another thing. Your title mentions the longtable package, but you're not using the longtable package. (Removing it does nothing.) You're using a longtblr from the tabularray package.

Comment: @frabjous you forgot to say the important consequence of your comment: **It's not David's fault**

Comment: It seems that you use code from my answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/643301/how-to-generate-long-tables-with-tabularray [it be nice to accept it, if you use it. ;-)], which works fine, without any warnings, errors or bad boxes. However your question is not clear what you after. Transformation my answer to standard table in `table` float? Is this is case, please edit your question and clearly stated this request.

Answer (score 1):

Let me assume, that you like to transform my answer to simple table in `table` float environment. Doing this, you should consider:

- `table` increase caption number, so the code line `\refstepcounter{table}` on the beginning of table and `\addtocounter{table}{-1}` at the end of table in my answer are not needed anymore. Even worse, they cause the problems which you described in question.
- Instead of `longtblr` use `talltblr` table.

After correcting that, the MWE is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{report}

\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{lavender}{rgb}{0.9, 0.9, 0.98}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex, 
            font=small,
            labelfont=bf]{caption}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]

\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\DefTblrTemplate{firsthead, middlehead,lasthead}{default}{} % <--- remoce caption generated by `talltblr`
    \begin{talltblr}[
 label={table:1}
            ]{
    colspec={|l l X[l]},
    colsep=6pt,
    row{odd} = {bg=lavender},
    row{1,2} = {bg=white},
    row{2} = {rowsep=0pt},
    row{3} = {font=\bfseries},
    column{1} = {bg=white, colsep=3pt},
    vline{1} = {abovepos = 1, belowpos = 1},
                }
    & \SetCell[c=2]{c} \textbf{Table \thetable}. Parameters for protein solvation calculations using APBSmem & \\
    \cline[1.5pt]{2,3} & & \\[-6pt]
    \cline[1.5pt]{2,3} & Parameter & Value \\
    \cline[1.5pt,gray]{2,3} & Calculation type & Protein solvation \\
    & Grid Dimensions & $\qtyproduct{289 x 289 x 257}{\angstrom}$ \\
    & Coarse Grid Lengths & $\qtyproduct{202.889 x 202.915 x 185.759}{\angstrom}$ \\
    & Fine Grid Lengths & $\qtyproduct{139.347 x 139.362 x 129.27}{\angstrom}$ \\
    & Counter-Ions & 1.0, 0.154, 1.65 \\
    & & $-1.0$, 0.154, 1.67 \\
    & Protein Dielectric & 2.0 \\
    & Solvent Dielectric & 80.0 \\
    & Membrane Dielectric & 8.0 \\
    & Headgroup Dielectric & 80.0 \\
    & Boundary Conditions & Focus \\
    & Solvent probe radius (srad) & 1.4 \\
    & Surface sphere density (sdens) & 10 \\
    & Temperature & 298.15 \\
    & Z-position of membrane bottom & $-23.9$ \\
    & Membrane thickness & 47.8 \\
    & Headgroup thickness & -- \\
    & Upper exclusion radius & 0 \\
    & Lower exclusion radius & 0 \\
    \cline[1.5pt]{2,3}
\end{talltblr}
    \end{table}
 \lipsum[66]   
    \begin{table}[ht]
\caption{The next table}
\label{table:2}
\begin{tblr}{hlines,vlines, 
              colspec={X[c]}
             }
dummy table for test of caption numbering and referencing.
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}

See table \ref{table:1} and \ref{table:2} ...
\end{document}
```

And result of compilation is:

[image]

**Edit:**
Added is dummy table for testing tables numbering and and referencing. Proposed solution is tested by use of  `tabularray` package 2022A, on myrecent MiKTeX instalaltion. Result of compilation, as proof that MWE works as it is, is below.

**Remark:**
Compilation on Overleaf unfortunately still not works since they still have installed "ancient" version of `tabilarray` package, which does not yet have `talltblr` defined. Regarding this problem the best is ask their team for help or meantime instead of `talltblr` use `longtblr` environment.

Comment: i accepted your last answer, and now i use your code once again, but i got an error:  Environment talltblr undefined. it should not be in the permeable, right? - according to this manual https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/tabularray/tabularray.pdf

Comment: @sphero, see edited answer. It seems, that you use Overleaf, which cause your new problem. BTW, you use code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/643301/how-to-generate-long-tables-with-tabularray answer, which you not accept yet.

Comment: i accepted the previous answer, you should be able to see that now... also accepted it before but no idea what happened!. well, i used the new edited answer, but still the same error: environment talltblr undefined. any other way to work this out, or should i directly report that to overleaf support team?

Comment: @sphero, do you really read answer? You not provide me relevant information: which version of `tabularray` you use, do you use Overleaf service? MWE as is, woks if are fulfilled condition mentioned in the edited answer!